# How to insert default value in html form text input using python?

Tags: python, html, forms

I'm unsure if I can achieve the following in python 3:

My idea is to populate the default value of a form element using the value of a variable within my python script, so that when I run the script, an HTML form shows up on the browser with input values defaulted from the variables I have set above the form. The syntax below is "obviously" not correct, and when I try to set the `value` to `num`, and then run it, a 500 internal error is shown on the browser.

Code:

```
num = 10
print("<html>")
print("<body>")
print("<form action="/myscript.py" method="post">")
print("<input type="text" name="maturity" value='"+str(num)+"'></input>")
print("</form>")
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

Comment: `print('<input type="text" name="maturity" value='+str(num)+'></input>')`

Answer (score 1):

Although I think you are not doing what you want.

```
num = 10
print(
"""
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/myscript.py" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="maturity" value='%s'></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
""" % str(num)
)
```

Comment: How do I get this to show up as an actual page? At the moment, when I run the script (which is on lighttpd), it shows up the html code above within the print statement

Comment: You consider it too simple, if you want to achieve what you need, you need to at least have a server. In order to build the whole stack, you need a framework like django or flask. Search them.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape quotation marks `"` with `\`

```
num = 10
print("<html>")
print("<body>")
print("<form action=\"/myscript.py\" method=\"post\">")
print("<input type=\"text\" name=\"maturity\" value='"+str(num)+"'></input>")
print("</form>")
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

Comment: But this prints out the html code, instead of showing a web form.